# How to get value for offline_post_auth_token in ejabberd?

Tags: erlang, push-notification, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd and then added a extra module (mod_offline_post)for Push messages.
 after installation i was configuring ejabberd.cfg according to instruction everywhere i need auth_token and post_url,

```
{mod_offline_post, [
        {auth_token, "offline_post_auth_token"},
        {post_url, "http://localhost:5280/offline_post"}
    ]},
```

Now i am confused what value will be entered in these two field and how i will get those.
Please help me,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The author of this module "mod_offline_post" uses Zero push API for sending push notification. As per my understanding the "offline_post_auth_token" is access token for "zero push" API, and "post_url" is the url to which you want to post ,offline messages. Please have a look http://symmetricinfinity.com/2013/01/23/ios-push-notifications-from-ejabberd.html